# Save file to path desktop for current user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, path, .net-core, export-to-excel

I have a project ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC running on IIS.
Want to Export some information from data grid to Excel and save it from web page to the desktop of current user.

```
                string fileName = "SN-export-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
                Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
                fileName = rgx.Replace(fileName, ".");
                string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                string fileName2 = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
                FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(fileName2);
                excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
```

This works perfect local at Visual Studio, but not after publishing at IIS.
Using simple path string path = @"C:\WINDOWS\TEMP"; It will save this export file at the server temp folder, but not current web page user.
How to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is framework for a web application. So you have fronted and backend parts. This code will executed on the server side of your application. Even if you use Razor pages, they also generated at the backend. So there are several ways to save data on the computer:

- use js to iterate data and save it, but I'm not sure that saving to excel with js is easy;
- send desired data to backend, save it to excel and then return to the client.

For a second way you can use next code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DownloadController : Controller {

    //GET api/download/12345abc
    [HttpGet("{id}"]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(YourData data) {
        Stream stream = await {{__get_stream_based_on_your_data__}}

        if(stream == null)
            return NotFound();

        return File(stream, "application/octet-stream"); // returns a FileStreamResult
    }   
}
```

And because of security reasons you can save data only to downloads directory.